# Why user is given a server certificate in first-network example of hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

From what I understand of ssl/tls you have certificate which is used for client/server authentication if you are going to act as server.
Admin or a simple user in any org(Orderer or peer) is given a server.crt
Can someone shed some light on why it is needed ?
Any help, highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  Users don't need those.  We just happen to use the same underlying code to generate the crypto material for peers, orderers and users so they all end up with a tls folder in their map folder.

If you think this is an issue or causes confusion, feel free to create a JIRA ticket at https://jira.hyperledger.org